# Change or Remove Default Return Values from PaginationSerializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-pagination

I am using the Django REST Frameworks Paginator to paginate the JSON responses read from a database.

My current serializers.py file looks like this:

```
class CountrySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    country_geoname_id = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    country_code = serializers.CharField(source="iso", max_length=2L, required=True)
    country_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=64L, required=True)

    paginate_by_param = "offset"

    def transform_iso(self, obj, value):
        return "country_code"

class PaginatedCountrySerializer(pagination.PaginationSerializer):
    paginate_by_param = "offset"
    class Meta:
        object_serializer_class = CountrySerializer
        paginate_by_param = "offset"
```

The request/response currently looks like this:

```
GET /v4/api/v1/countries/?limit=1&offset=1
{
    "count": 250, 
    "next": "http://dev.fanmode.com/v4/api/v1/countries/?limit=2&page=2&offset=1", 
    "previous": null, 
    "results": [
        {
            "country_geoname_id": 3041565, 
            "country_code": "AD", 
            "country_name": "Andorra"
        }, 
        ...
    ]
}
```

Could someone help me by telling me:

- How do I modify the names of these? for example I want to change where it says 'page=2' in the `next` field to 'limit=2'. I have tried `'PAGINATE_BY_PARAM': 'limit'` in the settings.py file but this didn't work.
- How do I remove fields all together. I want to remove 'count' and 'previous' from the response.

Appreciate any help I can get.
Thanks.

Comment: Changing `'PAGINATE_BY_PARAM': 'limit'` will not the `page=n` returned by the API, it simply allows you to use the other alternative as well.

Comment: @hcwhsa thanks for your reply. I thought that might be the case. Do you know how I change it in the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `page_field` in `NextPageField` class inside [`pagination.py`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/pagination.py) file to permanently change the name from `page` to `limit`.

For the second part you can write your own [custom `PaginationSerializer`](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination.html#custom-pagination-serializers):

```
from rest_framework.pagination import BasePaginationSerializer, NextPageField
class MyPaginationSerializer(BasePaginationSerializer):

    next = NextPageField(source='*')
```

Now only the `next` and `results` field will be returned.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do I link the MyPaginationSerializer to the serializer I am using? How does it know to use this serializer? I tried adding `pagination_serializer_class = MyPaginationSerializer` to the PaginatedCountrySerializer meta class but it didn't work. Thanks again.

Comment: @MarkWinterbottom Have a look at these exampled: http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination.html#paginating-querysets

Comment: PaginationSerializer is deprecated in django 1.8